# Is there a bash macro?

Tags: bash, macros

I am trouble shooting a bash script with some echo statements. Because the script is run from another process, I echo to a text file:

```sh
echo "…">>~/debug.txt
```

Does bash have some sort of macro which would let me write something like:

```sh
log "…"
```

I am using macOS, but I think the question is OS agnostic.

Failing a macro, what is the alternative?

Comment: The only macros in bash are readline / keyboard macros.  What you are talking about are shell functions or aliases.  They operate differently to macros (in the "bash" sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in one. You can create your own [function](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions) easily enough:

```
log() {
    echo "$@" >>~/debug.txt
}
```

Comment: Actually, the function fits perfectly. I should reword my question, since it doesn’t necessarily have to be a macro. I notice that I call it as `log "…"` without parentheses.

Comment: bash has aliases and functions but not macros, so presumably either would qualify as a solution.  There is also `set -x`